# Чоловічок чи комбінезон

Tags: вживання-слів

Як правильно назвати дитячий одяг "чоловічок" чи "комбінезон", в значенні суцільні штани та кофта?

В СУМ-11

> [Комбінезон](http://sum.in.ua/s/kombinezon) а, чол. Робочий одяг, що становить сполучення куртки
>   зі штанами.
>
> [Чоловічок](http://sum.in.ua/s/cholovichok) 1. Зменш.-пестл. до чоловік. //  Те саме, що дитина.

В інтернет-магазинах зустрічала обидва варіанти вживання

Чоловічки [1](https://garnamama.com/ua/baby-0-24-_cholovichki/kt691), [2](https://syndychok.ua/uk-ua/for-newborn/chelovechek-mishuta/)

Комбінезон [1](https://27.ua/ua/shop/kombinezon-detskiy-timi-teks-r-74.html), [2](https://kasta.ua/product/5849122:675/?from=detskiy-kombinezon-bryuki)

Answer (score 3):

### Комбінезон, комбінезончик

Очевидно, що значення слова *комбінезон* зараз ширше. Тепер це вже не лише робочий одяг, а будь-який (що становить сполучення тієї одежини, яку одягають на верхню частину тіла, і штанів).

Зокрема, «Словник української мови» в 20 томах каже:

> [КОМБІНЕЗО́Н](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43167&page=1362), а, ч. Костюм, що є поєднанням верхньої частини одежі та штанів. <…>

— де:

> КОСТЮ́М, а, ч. <…> 2. Одяг різного призначення, перев. з двох і більше частин. <…>

Також «Словник української мови» в 20 томах окремо визначає:

> [КОМБІНЕЗО́НЧИК](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=219491&page=1409), а, ч. Зменш.-пестл. до комбінезо́н. <…> *Я збирала Русланчика в село, до мами, на кілька днів. Колготки, джинсики, теплий комбінезончик…* (В. Яворівський); <…>.

Отже можемо сміливо використовувати *комбінезо́н* і *комбінезо́нчик*.

#### Чоловічок, людинка

###### Уживання

Починаючи з 2018, ЗМІ починають використовувати слово *чоловічок* (у цьому значенні), хоч і поодиноко:

- UNIAN.NET:

  > Це коробка-колиска, яка міститиме необхідні для малюка речі (пелюшки, підгузки, чоловічки, ковдри тощо). // 2018

  > До набору входять, зокрема: підгузки (не менше 94 штук в упаковці), вологі серветки (не менше 56 штук в упаковці), ситцеві пелюшки (розмір 80x95 см), фланелева, муслінова, а також багаторазова вологостійка пелюшки (розмір 60х80 см), дві шапочки, боді з коротким рукавом та боді з довгим рукавом, штани-повзунки, «чоловічки» з довгим рукавом та штанцями, шкарпетки. // 2018

  > Мають попит і дитячі карнавальні костюми: сукні, жилетки, чоловічки та костюми з героями мультфільмів. // 2020

  > Чоловічки з довгим рукавом та штанцями, бавовна 100%: розмір 56 см (довжина тіла 51-56 см) — 1, розмір 62 см (довжина тіла 57-62 см) — 2, розмір 68 см (довжина тіла 63-68 см) — 2, розмір 74 см (довжи на тіла 69-75 см) — 2. // 2021
- Zaxid.net:

  > …Чоловічки з довгим рукавом та штанцями: розмір 50-56 см, розмір 56-58 см… // 2018

  > …сім бавовняних «чоловічків» з довгим рукавом і штанцями (розмір 56, 62, 68, 74 см)… // 2019
- Українська правда:

  > Наприклад, у новому складі бебібоксу стало більше одягу — тепер в ньому є "чоловічки" аж до 74 розміру // 2021

  > У "пакунку маляти" є фактично все, що потрібно дитині в перші дні, — каже Юлія Ткаченко, лікар-неонатолог Київського міського пологового №6, — Але бебі-бокс видають вже після пологів, тому на самі пологи можна взяти шапочку, чоловічок, памперс та шкарпетки: всього по одному. // 2021
- Версії:

  > …Чоловічки з довгим рукавом та штанцями: розмір 50-56 см — 1; розмір 56-58 см — 1… // 2018
- Фіртка:

  > Це коробка-колиска, яка міститиме необхідні для малюка речі (пелюшки, підгузки, чоловічки, ковдри тощо). // 2018
- Хмарочос:

  > …чоловічки з довгим рукавом та штанцями; розмір 50–56 см; розмір 56–58 см… // 2018
- GALNET:

  > Спочатку потрібно зрозуміти, що буде зручніше — боді чи «чоловічки». // 2019
- НВ:

  > Чи є чоловічки для грудних з начосом? // 2020
- 04637.com.ua — сайт міста Прилуки:

  > До «пакунку малюка» входить все, що необхідно для новонародженого — підгузки, вологі серветки, пелюшки, бодіки, комбінезончик, чоловічки, шкарпетки, термометри для води, доглядова косметика, матрац та дитяча постіль, розвиваючі килимок та іграшки, рушники для купання і коробка-колиска. // 2021
- 04141.com.ua — сайт міста Новограда-Волинського:

  > В пакунок входить набір одягу (боді, чоловічки, ромпери, шапочки, шкарпетки), пелюшка, підгузки, килимок для сповивання, соска, пляшечка, засоби гігієни для мами та малюка, а також харчування як для немовляти, так і для матусі. // 2022

[Yola також наводить приклад](/a/5061) застосування варіанта *людинка*. Хоча, наскільки я можу судити, цей варіант уживають значно рідше.

(*Чоловічок* і *людинка* я шукав у «Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі української мови» версії 16. Для *людинки* не знайшов там траплянь у цьому значенні.)

###### Походження

Те, що варіант *чоловічок* значно домінує над, здавалося б логічнішим (адже основне значення слова [чоловік](http://sum.in.ua/s/cholovik) у сучасній українській мові — «людина саме чоловічої статі», а не «людина» загалом; хоча значення «людина» теж присутнє), варіантом *людинка*, справляє на мене враження, що це слово (точніше: використання цього слова в цьому значенні) запозичене з російської (де слово *человек* означає «людина», незалежно від статі).

Але під час швидкого пошуку інформації про використання російського *человечек* (у відповідному значенні) у російських джерелах я побачив, що росіяни, навпаки, приписують появу цього слова (у цьому значенні) українській мові чи українцям (хоча знайдені мною джерела аж ніяк не можна назвати авторитетними: [мультфільм](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhvFdE7AQtM&t=131s) і [боксерський форум](https://allboxing.ru/forum/index.php?topic=459.msg1027974#msg1027974)).

Якщо підсумувати ці два припущення, то виходить, що це слово (у цьому значенні) з'явилося на теренах України, але в російськомовному чи суржикомовному осередку… або ж… що принаймні одне з двох вищенаведених припущень неправильне (що теж цілком імовірно, враховуючи «строгість» логіки в першому припущенні і «надійність» джерел у другому).

###### Значення

Те, що 04637.com.ua (сайт міста Прилуки) окремо перераховує через кому «комбінезончик» і «чоловічки», наводить мене на думку, що значення цих слів не зовсім еквівалентні.

Суто інтуїтивно складається враження, що слово *чоловічок*/*людинка* витіснило лише частину значень словосполучення *дитячий комбінезончик*, а саме — «**внутрішній/легкий** дитячий комбінезончик» (на противагу теплому дитячому комбінезончику, який надягають у зимну погоду поверх іншого одягу). Щось схоже [каже Анатолій](/a/5701), звужуючи значення слова до комбінезончиків, **у яких сплять** (або можливо спати).

Утім, оскільки це слово (точніше вживання в цьому значенні) порівняно нове й остаточно не зафіксоване, точне значення цілком може бути швидко змінитися або вже зараз бути різним у різних осередках.

###### Висновок щодо слів *чоловічок*, *людинка*

Ці слова (у цьому значенні) порівняно нові, розмовні. Але зрештою рішення за вами.

Answer (score 2):

Ми кажемо *людинка*, всі наші знайомі також. Це пряма калька з російської, але поки іншого не знайшли.

А ось приклад з мережі:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Перш за все, якщо ми в проаналізуємо результати в Гуглі, то отримаємо:

808 000 - "Комбінезон"

228 000 - "Чоловічок"

Тобто варіант "[комбінезон](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD)" точно є відомішим (наприклад, я ніколи не чув варіанту "чоловічок"). Та й як зазначено у відповіді користувача Sasha, слово "комбінезон" є в СУМі, тому ми точно можемо його вживати.

Але я задумався, чому вживають "чоловічок". На жаль, якоїсь конкретної інформації мені не вдалося знайти. Але під час своїх пошуків я натрапив на цей [інтернет магазин](https://malyw.com.ua/p29522537-0543-kombinezon-yaselnyj.html), де пише:

> Їх ще називають "спальники" або "чоловічки"

І тут варто зазначити, що "чоловічок" - це фактично "спальний комбінезон для **немовлят**". Тобто, я припускаю, що коли ми говоримо про комбінезон як про одяг для дорослих або як про спецодяг, то ми можемо вживати лише слово "комбінезон", а не "чоловічок". "Чоловічок" - це лише комбінзон (зазвичай спальний) для дітей. Його ще називають "сліп" (якщо в Гуглі ввести "сліп для немовлят", то на картинках буде то й же "спальний комбінзон" чи "чоловічок"). Знайшов підтвердження своїх думок на сайті [Kid](http://kid-to-kid.com.ua/uk/news/shcho-take-cholovichok-abo-slip-dlya-novonarodzhenogo) (не офіційне джерело):

> **Чоловічок - комбінезон, в якому немовля спить**. Думки розійшлися від
>   якого англійського слова відбулася назва - від сну (спати) або від
>   ковзання (ковзати, рухатися легко). У кожному разі, в такому
>   комбінезоні маляті зручно і спати, і ворушити ручками-ніжками. **Сліп -
>   це не офіційна назва комбінезонів для новонароджених, а прийняте в
>   ужитку серед матусь**. У хороших магазинах на цінниках замість слова
>   «сліп» швидше за все буде написано «піжама», чоловічок. Як правило,
>   сліп для новонароджених робиться з 100%-го бавовняного трикотажу, але
>   бувають і байкові моделі, утеплені велюрові та флісові.

Одже, найкраще вживати слово "комбінезон" як для позначення спецодягу, так і для спального одягу для немовлят (хоча я б вживав словосполучення "спальний комбінезон"). А слова "чоловічок" та "сліп" - це розмовні варіанти.